# How to change values in Hashmap in firestore?

Tags: android, firebase, hashmap, google-cloud-firestore

I am storing a hashmap in firestore like this:

**Here is a database image**

[image: database image]

The problem is that when I am storing these values, **I don't know the keys and values**, because the user is entering the keys and values.

How would I access keys and change their values?

Comment: What is the exact data that you want to get?

Comment: @AlexMamo all the values of the tool also need to update those values.

Comment: Have solved the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you can make an additional metadata field, where you write down all the keys entered by the user, for example, in an array. It would look like:

```
tool {
  metadata: {
    0: "brand_name"
    1: "photo_model"
    ....
  }
  brand_name: "Sony"
  photo_model: "DSLR"
  ...
}
```

Or you can store it in any other way but the point is that when you get dataSnapshot of the doc, you first check for these metadata keys, collect them into an array, and only then you can build your custom Bundle or whatever your objects look like through a cycle